# Android bluetoothLeScanner and bluetoothLeAdvertiser not working together on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetoothlescanner, bluetoothleadvertiser

I have 2 separate services, one for starting `bluetoothLeAdvertiser` and others for `bluetoothLeScanner`.

Service class for using `bluetoothLeScanner` looks as follows

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    startScanning()
    return START_STICKY
}
private fun startScanning() {
    bluetoothAdapter?.bluetoothLeScanner?.startScan(scanCallBack)
    Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext, "Scanning Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

and Service class for `bluetoothLeAdvertiser` looks as follows

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    FileManagement.getInstance(applicationContext).writeToFile(TAG, "onStartCommand() called")
    startAdvertising()
    return START_STICKY
}
private fun startAdvertising() {
    bluetoothAdapter?.bluetoothLeAdvertiser?.let {
        val setting = AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED)
            .setConnectable(false)
            .setTimeout(0)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
            .build()

        val data = AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
            .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(true)
            .addServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString("00001827-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
            .build()

        it.startAdvertising(setting, data, advertiseCallback)
        Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext, "Advert Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

The issue is between `bluetoothLeScanner` and `bluetoothLeAdvertiser` only one of the callbacks is getting triggered.

Comment: The APIs may not allow the dual functionality to both scan and advertise at the same time. That being said it might be due to the power requirements as well. Try make them both low power.

Comment: @ThomasMorris That did not work... What I have observed is the only either of the callbacks is getting called (saw them in logs).. any idea?

Comment: Sorry it did'nt work, my next guess would be the dual functionality maybe a later feature in ble, therefore might require a higher API requirement. So possibly try on a "newer" phone may have a later update of ble. I am not sure if this is the case however, but could be.